# How a packet is passed in WLAN when source and destination are in different BSS but same LAN?

Tags: networking

When one station passes the packet to its AP, then how will the AP know that the destination is under which AP? When the packet goes from source to AP, where will the AP send it? how addresses will be put when packet travels from source, then to different APs and finally to the destination?

Comment: This looks more like it's about networking than programming - see the [help/on-topic]. Your question might find a better home at our sister site [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: ok thank you. i will post it there